# Why does the compiler give an " java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: x -error? (size depends on input)

Tags: java, encryption, arraylist, standard-deviation, vigenere

I am making a small program to guess the keylength of a vigenere-cipher, with a given length between 5-15, within java.
I do this by calculating standard deviations because of the transpositions.
But my real question is why I get an out of bound error in the array in the method "countFrequency". I can't seem to see where it goes out of bounds.

I know my program could be way more efficient, but I think it should work once this error is fixed.
My program code is below.

Thanks!

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

// Scanning the encrypted text

// private static char encryptedText[];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
Scanner scan = null;new Scanner(System.in);
scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int i;
int vectors[][];
System.out.println("Give the decrypted text: \n");
String encryptedText =  scan.next().toString();
vectors = makeArray();
vectors = countFrequency(vectors, encryptedText);
calculateDeviations(vectors);

// No need to scan more

if(scan!=null)
    scan.close();
}


private static void calculateDeviations(int[][] vectors) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int sumpowfreq;
    int freqpowsum;
    for(i=0;i<12;i++){
        double deviation =0;
        for(j=0; j<26;j++){
            sumpowfreq = sumPowwFreq(vectors,i);
            freqpowsum = freqPowwSum(vectors,i);
            deviation = Math.sqrt((sumpowfreq/26) - (freqpowsum/26));
        }
        System.out.println("The devation of " + j + " is " + deviation + ".");
    }

}


private static int freqPowwSum(int[][] vectors, int i) {
    int powsum=0;
    int sum=0;
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<26;j++){
        sum = sum + vectors[j][i];
    }
    powsum = sum * sum;
    return powsum;
}


public static int sumPowwFreq(int[][] vectors, int i) {
    int sum=0;
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<26;j++){
        sum = sum + (vectors[j][i] * vectors[j][i]);
    }
    return sum;
}

public static int[][] makeArray() {
// Making the 2-dimensional array and set it to 0
    int keySize;
    int letterFrequency[][] = new int[26][11];
    for(keySize=5;keySize<16;keySize++){
        int j;
        for(j=0;j<26;j++){
            letterFrequency[j][keySize-5] = 0;  
            }
        }
    return letterFrequency;
}


public static int[][] countFrequency(int freq[][], String encryptedText){
    int i,j,c;
    int splitSize;
    int ascii;
    String splittedText[];
    for(splitSize=5; splitSize<15; splitSize++){
        splittedText = splitText(splitSize, encryptedText);
        for(j=0;j<splitSize;j++){
            for(c=0;c<splittedText[j].length();c++){
                ascii= splittedText[j].charAt(c);
                ascii = ascii - 97; // because the ascii table starts at 97, 0 represents an 'a' now
                                    // and we assumed that the encrypted text only contained small letters
                freq[ascii][j]++;
            }
        }       
    }   

    return freq;
}


public static String[] splitText(int partLength, String encryptedText){
    int len = encryptedText.length();

    int amountparts = len / (partLength);
    String parts[] = new String[amountparts];

    // Break into parts
    int offset= 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < amountparts){
        parts[i] = encryptedText.substring(offset, Math.min(offset + partLength, len));
        offset += partLength;
        i++;
    }

    return parts;
}
```

}

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a runtime exception. Compiler cannot report it.

Comment: Show us the stacktrace.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the error line and see what goes bad :)

Comment: It seems like it's line 92, but can't find the real problem yet. (why it really goes out of bounds),
which is:

for(c=0;c<splittedText[j].length();c++){

Answer (score 0):

I am no crypto-freak but I went into your code and saw the exception. 
I think, your problem rather domain-specific than technical...

The nested for loops in countFrequency() expects the array splittedText to contain at least 15 elements.

- for 1) splitSize runs from 5 to 14
- for 2) for every splitSize,j runs
  from 0 to splitSize
- for 3) for every j, do something with the jth element of splittedText

The last for is important for the Exception:

> splittedText must contain at least 15 elements.

How many elements are in splittedText?

This is determined in splitText(int, String). This method is called within (for 1) with the current splitSize as partLength and the user-input as encryptedText. 
splitText returns an array with (encryptedText.length() / partlength) elements. So we have:

> splittedText.length() = (inputlength / splitSize)

For every splitSize (5 to 14), the input-length must hold following condition:

input-length/splitSize >= splitSize ; and this is equivalent to

> input-length >= splitSize * splitSize

for the splitSize of 14, your input must be greater than 196.

As far as I read, this is no constraint for vigenere-ciphers. And - btw - if you pass this first ArrayOutOfBoundException, you will run into the next Exception.